# How to dynamically check and increment div id's in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, jwplayer

I have a table of videos that use Longtail Video's JW player.  When you click on an image in the table the video launches in a modal with an id of `media modal`.  This is the page I'm talking about: http://www.calvaryccm.com/volunteer/featured-ministry.

This is the Javascript for the modal:

```
$(".mediamodal").unbind('click');
$(".mediamodal").click(function () {
    $('.reveal-modal-bg').unbind('click');
    $('.close-reveal-modal').unbind('click');
    $('#mediamodal').remove();
    $('body').append('<div id="mediamodal" class="reveal-modal large" style="width:675px; margin-left:-415px;"><div id="mediaplayer"><script type="text/javascript">SetupMediaPlayer("' + $(this).attr('rel').toLowerCase() + '");</script></div><div id="livepoll_min" style="padding-top:20px;"></div><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>"');
    $('#mediamodal').reveal({
        animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    });
    $('.reveal-modal-bg').click(function () {
        $("#mediaplayer").remove();
        socket.disconnect();
    });

    $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function () {
        $("#mediaplayer").remove();
        socket.disconnect();
    });
```

This works great on desktop browsers, but not on the iPad.  I looked up why this fails on Longtail's page and they said each needs a unique div id.  I realized that is a problem because I am generating the div onclick.

How do I change the div id for each video dynamically?

Comment: you coudl keep a counter and increment it for each click, ensuring a unique div id?

Comment: why not remove the div with the ID from the dom?  That way you just create a new one on click.. and remove when closed.  Since you are binding the events after creation anyways

Comment: IMHO if you're reaching such a point the design of your application in general has some major failure.

Comment: I thought reuse was the right answer too, but that's what OP is doing.  The container div and the player element are both recreated every time.  Therefore, you can't reuse the same id even if you remove it.

Comment: @JosephMarikle ah.. that's right.. that is wierd

Comment: What happens if you use a "mediaplayer" class rather than an id? (of course you'd still remove elements with that class) It seems like you're running into an issue because you're using an id to identify something that is non-unique.

Comment: @alexandernst How does this show his "...application in general has some major failure." Your comment might be more helpful if you identify why you say that.

Comment: @parKing means that he should try to use Backbone (replace with your favourite MVC library) and take care of the real application logic instead of trying to control "views" manually.

Comment: @alexandernst thanks for the clarification, and yes, a library designed for that could probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a global counter:

```
var hiImACounter = 0;

$(".mediamodal").unbind('click');
$(".mediamodal").click(function () {
    $('.reveal-modal-bg').unbind('click');
    $('.close-reveal-modal').unbind('click');
    $('#mediamodal' + hiImACounter++).remove(); // <--- increment after the operation
    $('body').append('<div id="mediamodal'+hiImACounter+'" class="reveal-modal large" style="width:675px; margin-left:-415px;"><div id="mediaplayer'+hiImACounter+'"><script type="text/javascript">SetupMediaPlayer("' + $(this).attr('rel').toLowerCase() + '");</script></div><div id="livepoll_min" style="padding-top:20px;"></div><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></div>"');
    $('#mediamodal'+hiImACounter).reveal({
        animation: 'fadeAndPop',                   //fade, fadeAndPop, none
        animationspeed: 300,                       //how fast animtions are
        closeonbackgroundclick: true,              //if you click background will modal close?
        dismissmodalclass: 'close-reveal-modal'    //the class of a button or element that will close an open modal
    });
    $('.reveal-modal-bg').click(function () {
        $("#mediaplayer"+hiImACounter).remove();
        socket.disconnect();
    });

    $('.close-reveal-modal').click(function () {
        $("#mediaplayer"+hiImACounter).remove();
        socket.disconnect();
    });
```